# PolyAnalyst: Is there a way for several users to repair a project?

Tags: nlp

Is it possible for several users to repair a project? It seems like only the owner is allowed to repair it.

I have tried to make the owner a user group that includes several users but that did not work. For projects in production we usually need access to several users to be able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Ver. 6.5.22, the owner of a project or a PolyAnalyst administrator may change the ownership of a project to a user group (by right clicking on the project and select Access Rights > Change Owner.) After that, any user from that group can repair the project.